# How to center a div with rounded edges via CSS that includes a jquery slide-show image element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dreamweaver

I have attempted several suggested actions to center a rounded border around my image slide show. I have a .center class in my css style sheet that I am using; it works for the slider image if I place the class name in my slider div tag. However, the rounded image tag maintains left-alignment. Any direction is appreciated:

CSS:

```
@charset "utf-8";
h1 {
}

body {
}

#rcorners1 {

border-radius: 25px;
border: 2px solid #8AC007;
padding: 15px; 
width: 1171px;
height: 400px;
position:relative;

}


.center {
margin: auto;
width: 60%;
padding: 1px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Believers</title>
        <link href="../css/bot.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../jquery/jquery.cycle.all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#slider').cycle({});
    </script>
    <body>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <div id="rcorners1" class="center">
            <div id="slider"> 
                <img src="flower_nature.jpg" width="1171" height="400" alt=""/>
                <img src="nature_tree.jpg" width="1171" height="400" alt=""/> 
                <img src="river_nature.jpg" width="1171" height="400" alt=""/>
                <img src="sky_nature.jpg" width="1171" height="400" alt=""/> 

            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I does work: http://jsfiddle.net/kfrozw9k/ is just added the id to the center class, i guess the width has been overwritten.

Comment: @user2040772 For some reason, not working for me in DreamWeaver CC 2015

Comment: than try this: http://jsfiddle.net/kfrozw9k/2/ - its the same but not using the center class (which you actually wont need)

Comment: @user2040772 That worked, thanks!!!

Comment: can u provide an image of how it should look like.i want to help you :)

Comment: @aimme Thanks, but it was solved.